# File Name generated by passed variable getting special character appended

Tags: unix

I'm creating an archive filename by combining output folder and output file name which are both passed variables.
Example tar -czf $output_folder/$output_file.tar.gz.
However the generated file is getting an unicode character  U+25AA appended, so it looks like output_fileU+25AA.tar.gz. What could be causing this? - I'm testing it on a Windows machine

Comment: Try enclosing the filename within double quotes - `"myarchive.tar.gz"`

Comment: @DeepakDevanand Tried it, but still having the issue.

Comment: Is `tar` utility from [gnu32win](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/)? Looks like terminal is mapping a character to [U+25AA](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+25AA). Try "myarchive.tgz" or "myarchive\.tgz".